# ssrs column visibility inside row groups

Tags: sql, reporting-services

i have a report that has multiple groups mostly in rows and one column group but i need to show certain columns based on parameters selected. As show in the image when i right click on speciality column the column visibility is not available. Can somebody help me on this.

thanks

[image]
<sub>(source: [ravidowluri.com](http://www.ravidowluri.com/untitled.png))</sub>

Comment: can somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: Does the properties window give you visibility field? What about selecting other cells of the column like the header cell rather than the column?

Comment: No visibility in properties window. If i set visibile = false on the column header then the remaining rows for that columns shows or empty space.

Comment: Beware of setting visibility to False in Properties sidebar - it vanishes and you can't click it again to set the Toggle Item!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself without using visibility option in columns instead hide and show the header text based on parameter value and border style in properties window

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Visibility can be set in the Properties sidebar for that group column.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by selecting all the cells (one at a time) under the group header(s)/column and setting the associated text box Hidden to "true"