# ssrs setting column visibility on rowgroup

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to hide a column but it belongs in the RowGroups area. Unfortunately, the Column Visibility is greyed out and disabled. I'd like to just hide the column under certain conditions (using expressions) but keep the grouping.

I found a similar question on SO but its solution did not work for me. Is there a workaround for this?

[ssrs column visibility inside row groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522848/ssrs-column-visibility-inside-row-groups)

I've tried shifting some of the columns to the body area of the tablix, but then I can't merge cells vertically. I'm not sure what my options are.

In the image below, I'm trying to hide the first column but the Column Visibility option is disabled.
[image: Trying to hide the entire first column].

SSRS 2008 R2

Answer (score 7):

Are you trying to remove Column 1?
If you right click on the column header and choose **Delete Column** it will prompt you to either **delete column and associated groups** or **column only**. If you choose column only the grouping should remain.

Comment: Sorry, the original post was missing one piece. I only want to hide it under certain conditions. It should be visible otherwise.

Comment: @Gabe Ok, yes that does change things. Can you still delete the column like I suggested above. Then re-add it as just a standard column,not grouped (like column 2) and then try the visibility.

Answer (score 6):

You can choose a column and then navigate to Visibility property in the property bar. You can enter expressions there as well as just choosing true or false. However in this case it would just leave a space instead of that field.

Comment: Works as advertised, but leaving the space (as opposed to collapsing the space) is problematic.  Still, I had the same issue as the OP and this gets me part of the way there.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with the grayed out column visibility and the solutions I found online weren't working, so hopefully this will help someone else out.

You have to basically trick it into working.  Here’s how I did it:

1. Click on the tablix, then right click on the gray column properties thing on the column to the right of the column you’re interested in.
2. Choose Add Group>adjacent left.
3. In the group by field, enter False because you don’t really want it to group.
4. Now you can right click on the gray column properties box and choose visibility.
5. Enter your function for visibility.
6. Now copy and paste everything you need from the ‘broken’ column where you couldn’t adjust the visibility into your new column.
7. Delete the old column.

Comment: I was following the step above, but I don't see #2 Add Group>Adjacent Left.  There's only Adjacent Above and Adjacent Below.

Comment: This kind of works: it displays it as a row feature and so will display the value of `Test - Merged Cell` on every row (instead of as a merged cell i.e. once for the group).

Comment: Zippity! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the column
2. Select the option "Delete columns only"
3. Add a new column (without an associated row group)
4. Assign the field to the new column

The new column will use the row group as the granularity is equal.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually accomplishes the requested behavior.

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio, below design box, you can find row groups & column groups, right side of column group you can find down arrow, if you click on that you will find [ advance mode]
once it is opened, right click on the first row group, click group property, select visibility , click on hide

[image]
[image]

Done, Pl check

Comment: That doesn't allow me to hide the column conditionally using expressions, I don't think.

Answer (score -2):

On the details row group add list of column you want the data to be grouped by.

Comment: It would help if you could explain why you think this achieves what the OP wants; right now, I can't understand the relevance.