# SSRS Column visibility expression in Groups

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report where I am grouping by Main Client, Client, Year, Quarter, Month, Date and Day.  I have a request to add a new field after the client field called Hierarchy then I have to apply the column visibility in the Hierarchy field.

```
=iif(parameters!ShowAllClientMetrics.Value="true",False,True)
```

When I attempt to add the column visibility expression on the new grouped field Hierarchy the column visibility is grayed out.  I need an understanding why column visibility expression is not allowed in the grouping area and is there an alternative way to apply the column visibility expression on the new field?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose a column and then navigate to Visibility property in the property bar. You can enter expressions there as well as just choosing true or false

Comment: Okay. That leaves a blank column in between the Sub Client and Year.

Comment: try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891704/ssrs-setting-column-visibility-on-rowgroup