# SSRS - How to hide a row while context menu "Row Visibility" is disabled?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS 2008 integrated into VS 2008. All I want to do is to hide a Note row based on parameter, e.g my param is "Display Note". However my row which is containing my Note is somehow disabled "Row Visibility" feature. Please advise how I can hide Note row which does not leave a gap there.

Row Visibility is disabled

[image]

Regards,

Kelvin

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522848/ssrs-column-visibility-inside-row-groups

Answer (score 1):

The Row Visibility property there is disabled because it's a header row. You can add a fake row group to control visibility of the last column group.

1. Move the Note column down as the last group.
2. Right-click on your first row group cell and select Add Group -> Adjacent Above.
3. Set the grouping expression for this new row group to "1" and remove any sorting.

[image]

4. Delete the header row that had the Note grouping, but make sure you only delete the rows, not the group.

[image]

5. Now you can set the visibility of your top row group which will cover the Note column group.
   [image]

Comment: @KelvinNguyen Glad it helped, I know it's not straightforward. Please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Row-group to select it and then, in the properties pane, set the "Hidden" property to True.