# How to remove the empty space in SSRS matrix when columns in rowgroup are hidden?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am working on a matrix/tablix in SSRS. I have some columns in the rowgroups and I am trying to hide them based on the expression. The hiding part works fine but  there is empty space when the columns are hidden. Any ideas on how to hide the empty space? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*You need to copy all Tablix/matrix/Textboxes Inside the rectangle to fix Empty Space issue.*

So First of all, cut all the Tablix/matrix and add the rectangle and make size of it like it was occupied before for Tablix/Matrix. Then paste cut part to rectangle. It will definitely work.

**Note:** *Do not remove visibility expression.*

*Please let me know it doesn't work for you.*

Comment: I tried dragging and dropping the whole matrix in a similar size rectangle but it didnt seems to work. Still having the empty space problem.

Answer (score 0):

The visibility expression needs to be set on the **column** itself, not on the cells/texboxes.

[image]

EDIT:

Only certain rows and columns can be hidden. It has to do with crossing groupings in the matrix. See my answer to a similar problem here [SSRS - How to hide a row while context menu "Row Visibility" is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288571/ssrs-how-to-hide-a-row-while-context-menu-row-visibility-is-disabled/37305657#comment62316256_37305657)

Comment: I am not getting the visibility(greyed out) option because it is a column in the row group.